# How to determine if a function with a given name exist in Javascript / jQuery?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Given a function name as a string, how could I determine if such function exist (globally), and if yes, call to this function ?

I tried to do:

```
function foo() {
    alert("foo called");
}

var func_name = "foo";

if (typeof window[func_name] == 'function') {
  foo();
} else {
  alert(func_name + " is not defined!");
}
```

[But, it doesn't seem to work.](http://jsfiddle.net/CpLLd/)

Comment: Which browser did u check it?

Comment: Try the code by saving it to your local machine it will work

Comment: @AmGates only because it won't have been wrapped inside an `onLoad` handler.

Comment: Alnitak is right. Running your code in a browser seems to work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason your jsfiddle doesn't work is because the named function has been defined within jsfiddle's default `onLoad` wrapper.

This means that the function is only defined within the scope of that closure, and isn't added to the global object.

For testing purposes, just add your function explicitly to the global object by declaring it as:

```
window.foo = function() ...
```

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense. One last question: I would like to replace `foo();` with a function call based on `func_name`. Is `eval` the only way to do so?

Answer (score 2):

I took a look and it seems to work in my browser console, but not in the fiddle.  I was able to get it to work in fiddle by explicitly attaching the function to window:

```
window.foo = function() {
    alert("foo called");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function foo() {
    alert("foo called");
}

var func_name = "foo";
var funcObj = null;

try {
funcObj = eval(func_name);
funcObj();
} catch(e) {
    // no function defined
}
```

Comment: I wonder if I could avoid `try & catch` and `eval` (or at least one of them).

Comment: you can use a new Function instead of eval

Answer (score 0):

Try with window[func_name]  instanceOf Function or you can use jquery.isFunction method

Answer (score 0):

Your code works if you change the way you declare the function (if you can do that)

```
foo = function() {
    alert("foo called");
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uzuc2/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you not to use the typeof variable === 'function', I prefer a function for checking a type, instead of the regular type checking. This approach saved me and  my colleagues life many times.  For example:

```js
isFunction = function(val) {
    return typeof val == 'function' && val.call !== 'undefined';
};

window.foo = function() {
    alert("foo called");
};

var func_name = "foo",
    /*for testing purpose*/fn = foo; // fn = window[func_name];

if (isFunction(fn)) {
    fn();
}
else {
    alert(func_name + 'is not defined!');
}
```

ps: the provided example is not the most perfect version of checking a function type because in IE cross-window calls function appears as object.

Answer (score -1):

This should help you

```
if(typeof myFunctionName == 'function') myFunctionName()
```

Look at this [link](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/determinevar2.shtml) to seemore info about typeof operator

**UPDATE**

```
if(eval("typeof window."+myFnName) == 'function') eval(myFnName+"()");
```

But like the others stated, your original code works as expected.

Comment: The function name is given as a string!

Comment: Oh, sorry. See Updated answer.

Comment: why whould you eval the "typeof" expression?

Comment: Well this is one aproach. It is because of myFnName is a string, so I eval it as a whole to get function/undefined result. I've corrected one more thing, so now it's more clear. However the original OP's code is propably better solution as I see now.